# Is there a way to create Kafka like topics in AWS kenesis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to create different topics in aws kinesis but can’t find a way to do so.. I tried using partition key to read data that was produced using that key which works kind of fine but its not the best solution. Can someone suggest how to create Kafka like topics in aws kinesis?

Comment: A Kinesis stream is equivalent to a Kafka topic. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @kdgregory I have different producers, each producer produces data of specific topic. I need data of each topic from each of the producers at one place to perform some analysis. 

From what you say, I think I need to make seperate stream for every producer and then read data from all those streams together to perform analysis. Please correct me if I am wrong, I am new to this. 

Thank You

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you need to do. Beware, however, that if you have a large number of producers, the costs add up quickly (each shard is about $0.50/day), and Kafka or another mechanism may be more cost-effective.